# How to change a color of a specific character in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

Sorry I am new to this. Please forgive any ignorance.

I have a table that contains several random characters in columns B,D,F,and H.

These characters range from 0-9 and A-Z (both upper case and lower case).

I want to find all of the like characters in each of the columns and change their color. I want to repeat this for each of the available characters. Can someone please help me?

I found [this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/94605-change-color-single-character.html) earlier that is pretty close to what i am trying to do.

This was the code that the respondent said would work.

```
Sub Test1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cell As Range, i As Integer, cellVal As String
With Columns(1)
.SpecialCells(2, 3).Font.ColorIndex = 1
For Each cell In .SpecialCells(2, 3)
cellVal = cell.Text
For i = Len(cellVal) To 2 Step -1
If cell.Characters(i, 1).Text = "s" Then cell.Characters(i, 
1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
Next i
Next cell
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When i try this is doesnt affect the characters in my table.

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Are your values hard-coded, or the result of formulas?  This won't work on formulas.

Comment: The values are hard - i typed them myself.

Comment: How long are the values?  I don't think this will work for text >255 characters long.

Comment: The values contain <70 characters.

Comment: Your code works for me with no changes.

Comment: Really. Does it Change the color in column "A"? What was the value you typed in?

Comment: Yes I typed some random text containing "s" in a couple of cells in colA and the letter "s" was highlighted.    It's possible your color palette is different from mine and colorindex 3 is also black though...   You could instead try `.Color = vbRed`

Comment: Do I have to change the name to my worksheet or excel to mTch this code?

Comment: That code just acts on whichever is the active sheet

Answer (score 0):

The code above will only change the values in the first column after the first character to red if it is "s".
I changed the above code, I think this is more what you want:

```
Sub ChangeCellCharacterColors()
Dim cell As Range, i As Integer, cellVal As String
For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Cells 'Enter sheet name and range of cells to iterate through
cellVal = cell.Text
    For i = 1 To Len(cellVal)
        If cell.Characters(i, 1).Text = "B" Then cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 4 'Identify character "B" and color index 4(green)
        If cell.Characters(i, 1).Text = "D" Then cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
        If cell.Characters(i, 1).Text = "F" Then cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        If cell.Characters(i, 1).Text = "H" Then cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 5
    Next i
Next cell
End Sub
```

Old Answer for reference:

You can create rules for which colors your cell displays based on the specific text contained in the cell.

Select the cells you want to format

Home->Conditional formatting->New Rule->Format only cells that contain.

Then change 'cell value' to 'specific text'.

'Format...' button to change color fill

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. I'm using Excel '10 are these directions still valid? I tried to follow them but i get lost when i click on conditional formatting and then try to find color scales.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry i followed the directions.. Been a long day.

Comment: I might not have explained my problem well. Each of the cells has their own unique set of characters ranging from 0-9 A-Z (including lower case). I want to find all of the "A" located in each of the cells and turn them lets say red. Then i want to find all of the "B" and change them a different color. So on and so fourth until all the characters are covered. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: Thanks, Tim said that the code I posted above works for him. For some reason I can't get it to work for me.

Comment: The code will work in column A for a value like "test". I modified my answer so you just need the sheet name and cell range of your table. Also didn't know what colors you wanted for the letters.

Comment: Is there a way I can post my workbook? I have no idea why this isn't working for me.

Comment: Have you run other programs with vba before? I don't know of a way to share the workbook on here, but you can send it to me at patrickscool@gmail.com. It should be a macro-enabled excel file.